# How to find the variance of this p.d.f?

Tags: statistics, expectation

X is distributed so that:
$$X=\begin{cases}
\frac{ x-80}{400}&  80\le x \le 100\\
\frac{120-x}{400} &  100\le x\le 120\\
 0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$Var(X)= E((X)^2)-(E(X))^2$ and $E(X)=100$ by symmetry, so what has me confused is how to go about finding $E((X)^2)$ because of the 'split' in the p.d.f.

Thanks!

Comment: Can the question be seen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expectation is an integral, if you have a pdf which is 'splitted', you can take the sum of the integral such that $$E(X^2) = \int_{range1} x^2f(x)_{part1}dx + \int_{range2} x^2f(x)_{part2}dx $$

I hope that anwsers your question

Answer (score 2):

Where $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator function,
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{400} (x-80) \mathbf{1}_{80\leq x\leq 100}+\frac{1}{400} (120-x) \mathbf{1}_{100\leq x\leq 120}$$
Moments: $$E(X^n)=\frac{2^{2 n+1} 5^n \left(2^{2 n+3}+2^{n+1} 3^{n+2}-5^{n+2}\right)}{(n+1) (n+2)}$$
Mean: $n=1$, $E(X)=100$

So the variance $V(X) =E(X^2)-E(X)^2=\frac{200}{3}$